# google maps api v3 trigger street view on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm recently new in the google map api v3, and wanted to ask if there is any way I could trigger the street view mode just by clicking a link in my infoBox.

so far this is my code:

```
var map;
var marker;
var infowindow;

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {controlDiv.style.margin = '50px 0 0 0';}

 function initialize() {
   var location = new google.maps.LatLng(37.78391, -122.407157);
   var mapOptions = {
                       center: location,
                       zoom: 18,
                       panControl: false,
                       scrollwheel: false,
                       zoomControl: false,
                       scaleControl: true,
                       streetViewControl: true,
                       streetViewControlOptions: {
                               mapTypeControl: true,
                               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
                       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                        mapOptions);

                       marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: map.getCenter(),
                                    map: map,
                                    title: 'Click to zoom'
                       });

                       var boxText = document.createElement("div");
                       boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 26px; background:   url('inc/images/infowindow-overlay.png') repeat left top; padding: 15px 20px;";
                                boxText.innerHTML = "<span class='pointing-arrow'></span><h2 class='adress-title'>San Francisco Center</h2><a href='#'>Centre Website</a><a href='#'>Street View</a>";

                       var myOptions = {
                                    content: boxText,
                                    disableAutoPan: false,
                                    maxWidth: 0,
                                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-5, 0),
                                    zIndex: null,
                                    boxStyle: {width: "280px"}
                                };


                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                                mapOptions);
                                var image = 'inc/images/westfield-marker-logo.png';
                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: location,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: 'Westfield HQ',
                                    draggable: true,
                                    icon: image
                                });

                                //infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                    map.setZoom(18);
                                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                                    ib.open(map, this);
                                });

                                var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                            }
                            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

now what I want to do is that, in the part where I initialize the boxText, and add the mark-up, i want the street view anchor tag to initialize the street view onclick.

I've found some options in the documentation like centering the map to the marker by clicking external links, but couldn't find any to activate the street view on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle a click event on an element inside an `InfoBox` (or an `InfoWindow`) is a little convoluted.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate how it's done. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ5Uj/)

Basically, you write your click handler like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(ib.content_,'click',(function(marker) {
    return function() {
      openStreetView(); // Here's where you activate the StreetViewPanorama
    }
})(marker));
```

I didn't include details about how to activate a StreetViewPanorama through code, since there's plenty of information on that subject in the [Google Maps JS API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas).

**EDIT**

I just realized that this handler runs anytime you click *anything* inside the InfoBox which is not exactly what you asked for. To achieve exactly what you want (event handler on the 'Street View' link inside the InfoBox), I had to use a little jQuery. Here's the updated fiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ5Uj/2/)**

Here, you create the content of the InfoBox as a jQuery element, so you can bind a `click` handler to the 'Street View' link. (I gave `#swl` as an id to that link, so I could `find` it with jQuery.)

```
var boxObj = $("<div style='margin-top: 26px; background: url('inc/images/infowindow-overlay.png') repeat left top; padding: 15px 20px;'><span class='pointing-arrow'></span><h2 class='adress-title'>San Francisco Center</h2><a href='#'>Centre Website</a><a href='#' id='swl'>Street View</a></div>");

boxObj.find('#swl').on('click', function(){
    openStreetView();
});
```

It's not the prettiest code (you should create a css class and move all style definitions under that class) but it gets the job done. I'm sure you can clean it up and make it production worthy :)

Comment: Still it doesn't works, I don't know why. I cant see anything running in the jsfiddle either. Could you be more specific.

Comment: You think the Fiddle doesn't work, because you expected a full solution where the StreetView opens etc. I didn't write the code to open the Street View, I only showed you how you can handle the click inside the InfoBox. I'm not going to do your job for you. Read the docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas) and see how you can activate StreetView with code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've made it work. Since i'm new in this I didn't knew how things work but it helped me a lot, and learned a new thing.